# How to provide subnet access to the internet via IGW?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am new to AWS and trying to create VPC, Subnet and trying to give a Lambda permission to access internet.

So I am trying to give a subnet access to the internet via IGW.

However, steps are not clear to me.

Wondering can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Comment: lambda does not need any permissions to access internet, unless placed in a VPC. Is there a specific reason to place your lambda function in a VPC?

Comment: my lambda cannot talk with redshift even they are in the same VPC.

Comment: You would have to provide details of your VPC setup, SGs, Redshift and more. Your question does not give all details to pin-point a possible cause of mis-configuration or mis-use. Do you use redhsift data api? Does lambda have permissions for that? Does it have permissions to even work in VPC? Does your lambda can interact with other services in the VPC, or it does not work with anything?

Answer (score 0):

To provide an AWS Lambda function with access to the Internet, you have two options:

- **Option 1:** Do *not* associate the function with a VPC. This will automatically grant the Lambda function access to the Internet (but *not* to a VPC).
- **Option 2:** Associate the Lambda function with a **private subnet** in a VPC. Launch a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a public subnet in the same VPC, and edit the private subnet's Route Table to point `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to the NAT Gateway / NAT Instance.

You also mention the desire to allow the Lambda function to connect with an Amazon Redshift database. There are two ways to communicate with Redshift:

- Open a JDBC connection to Redshift *within* the VPC. This also requires the security group associated with the Redshift database to permit inbound connections on port 5439 from the security group associated with the Lambda function. *OR*
- Use the [Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html) to communicate via the Redshift endpoint on the Internet. This option does *not* require access to the VPC.

Therefore, if you want the function to communicate with both the Internet *and* a Redshift database, I would recommend *not* associating the function with the VPC. Then, use the Redshift Data API.

Comment: I already have the Lambda function within the VPC. The Redshift is within the same VPC. Wondering it does not work then?

Comment: They are within the same security group.

Comment: Merely putting resources in the "same" security group does not allow them to communicate with each other. The Security Group is **applied to each resource individually**. The correct setup would be a Security Group on the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) with default settings, and a separate Security Group on the Redshift database (`Redshift-SG`) that permits inbound traffic on 5439 from `Lambda-SG`.

Comment: I followed these steps and created Security Group on the Lambda function (Lambda-SG) with default settings and added that to inbound rule associated with Redshift with no luck.

Comment: To confirm whether it is the Security Group causing the problem, you could temporarily open port 5439 to "Anywhere". If it still fails to connect, then the problem lies elsewhere (eg perhaps with your code that is connecting to Redshift, or some other networking option).